# Freeing a generators resources after iterating only over a part of the sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, garbage-collection, generator

I would like to parse a string line by line and provide a generator for the results of each parse. The code that iterates over these results may choose not to iterate over the full sequence if it finds the information it wants:

```
import StringIO

def foo(string):
  sstream = StringIO.StringIO(string)
  for line in sstream:
    res = doSomethingWith(line)
    yield res
  sstream.close()

for bar in foo(mystring):
  if condition(bar):
     break
```

I presume, that this will leave `sstream` open if `condition(bar)` becomes `True`. What is the best way to guarantee that `sstream` will be closed when we're finished iterating over `foo()`? Will I have to wrap the generator in a class definition and implement `__del__`? Or can I rely on garbage collection here? I plan to call `foo()` for a lot of different strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to guarantee that `sstream` will be closed when
>   we're finished iterating over `foo()`?

In the general case of a 'cleanup' function that *absolutely* has to be called, you'll probably have to call it outside of the generator with something like...

```
from StringIO import StringIO

def foo(sstream):
    for line in sstream:
        res = doSomethingWith(line)
        yield res

sio = StringIO(mystring)
try:
    for bar in foo(sio):
        if condition(bar):
            break
finally:
    sio.close()
```

Context managers don't seem to work inside generators unless they're exhausted. For example...

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def my_stringio(s):
    print 'creating StringIO'
    sio = StringIO(s)
    yield sio
    print 'calling close()'
    sio.close()

def mygen():
    with my_stringio('abcdefghij') as sio:
        while 1:
            char = sio.read(1)
            if not char:
                break
            yield char

for char in mygen():
    print char
    if char == 'c':
        break
```

...never prints `'calling close()'`.

> Will I have to wrap the generator in a class definition and implement
>   `__del__`?

That's another option, but the problem with that approach is that if you somehow manage to create a circular reference with a class instance, the `__del__` method will never get called.

> Or can I rely on garbage collection here?

In this case, you can.

With a `StringIO` it doesn't really matter if you call the `close()` method. The only thing you might want to ensure is that the memory it was using has been garbage-collected, which will happen regardless of the way your `for` loop terminates - the generator will go out of scope, and its locals will be GC'd.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Nevermind the broken nonsense below; as far as I know you would need to perform the break in the for loop where the yield is located.

Might something like this work? I could easily be overlooking something.

```
import StringIO

# perform the break on the inner forloop first, to ensure sstream gets closed
break_ = false
def foo(string, break_):
  sstream = StringIO.StringIO(string)
  for line in sstream:
    res = doSomethingWith(line)
    if not break_: yield res
    else: break
  sstream.close()

for bar in foo(mystring, break_):
  if break_:
      break
  elif condition(bar):
     break_ = True
```